# overloading friend template operator-

Tags: c++, c++11

My code

```
template <typename T>
class myclass;

template <typename T>
myclass<T> operator+(const myclass<T>& a, const myclass<T>& b);
template <typename T>
myclass<T> operator-(const myclass<T>& a, const myclass<T>& b);

template <typename T>
class myclass {
  friend myclass operator+<>(const myclass& a, const myclass& b);
  friend myclass operator-<>(const myclass& a, const myclass& b);
};

template <typename T>
myclass<T> operator+(const myclass<T>& a, const myclass<T>& b){
  // ...
}

template <typename T>
myclass<T> operator-(const myclass<T>& a, const myclass<T>& b){
  // ...
}
```

getting this error

> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'

on line "friend myclass operator-<> ..."

Overloading operator+ works well, but does not work when overloading operator-. What's the problem? Thank you

Comment: Show the working `operator+` as well please.

Comment: You need a `;` after the `myclass` declaration

Comment: Ok my mistake, just added the missing semicolon and overloaded operator+ . The problem remains unsolved

Comment: Try `friend myclass operator-<T>...` Though MSVC 2017 takes the code as written, without error.

Comment: After the fixes I can compile it fine.

Comment: g++ 5.1.0 copy/paste - clean compile

Comment: Must be my compiler then. Thanks for all the help